# How can I modify the value in list pair by pair in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got the following piece of code:

```
# defines a square with 4 vertices: (1, 1), (1, 5), (5, 5), (5, 1)
coords = [1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1]
new_coords = []
for i in range(0, len(coords), 2):
   x = transform_x(coords[i])
   y = transform_y[coords[i + 1])
   new_coords.append(x)
   new_coords.append(y)
```

Can I rewrite it using a one-line list init (if not, what's the most concise method to do it)? E.g.:

```
new_coords = [... for x, y in nums[::2], nums[1::2]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can zip the slices for x and y in a nested list comprehension:

```
new_coords = [i for x, y in zip(coords[::2], coords[1::2]) for i in (transform_x(x), transform_y(y))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
coords = [1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1]
new_coords = [(coord) for coord in zip(coords[::2], coords[1::2])]
print(new_coords)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 5), (5, 5), (5, 1)]
```

**Edit**

You can also call the `transform_x` and `transform_y` functions inline:

```
[(transform_x(x), transform_y(y)) for x, y in zip(nums[::2], nums[1::2])]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
new_coords = [transform_x(coords[i]) if i % 2 == 0 else transform_y(coords[i]) for i in range(len(coords))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just alternating:

```
new_coords = [transform_y(c) if n % 2 else transform_x(c) for n, c in enumerate(coords)]
```

This is assuming you want `new_coords` to be a list, like `coords`, as in the longer example code.